# $P(X \geq t) \leq \frac{E(X^2)}{E(X^2) + t^2}$, where $E(X) = 0$ and $E(X^2)$ is finite.

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm trying to prove the above inequality. I've tried the following; note I make use of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality and the fact that $I$ is an indicator function:

$$|(t-X)I(t-X>0)|^2 \leq \\E[(t-X)^2]E[(I(t-X>0))^2] \\
= (t^2 + E(X^2))P(t-X >0) =\\ t^2 + E(X^2),$$ since $(t-X) \leq (t-X)I(t-X>0) \implies P(t-X>0) \geq 1 \implies P(t-X>0)=1.$

Now I'm a bit stuck. I have tried relating $t^2 + E(X^2)$ to $|t-X|^2$ but am not making progress. I'm trying to think of how we can bring $P(X\geq t)$ into the mix as well, since eventually we will obviously need it!

EDIT: $t \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $t$ is not necessarily positive, then I think this is wrong.

Let $X\equiv 0$.
For $t=-1$ you get
$$1=\mathbb P(X\geq -1)\leq 0 = \frac{0}{0+1}\implies 1\leq 0\implies \unicode{x21af}$$

---

Another example would be to take $X\sim Ber(1/2)$, and pick $t= -1$.
You get:
$$1=\mathbb P(X\geq -1)\leq \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{1+1}\implies 1\leq\frac{1}{2}\implies \unicode{x21af}$$

I think there are a lot more cases, where this does not apply.

---

Comment: But $X$ can be negative.

Comment: In the first example it can't, and I don't see where you said it can't.

Comment: maybe there is additional requirement that $t\ge 0$

Comment: Ahh yes, I'm sorry. $t$ is non-negative.

Comment: So we can use Chebyshev's Inequality to go about proving this?

Comment: I could not... :(

Comment: What was the problem with it?

Comment: As inifinity suggested, this yields a weaker bound.

Answer (score 0):

$
\begin{aligned}
    &(t-X)\leq (t-X)\textbf{1}\{t-X>0\}\\
    \Rightarrow&0\leq t=\mathbb{E}[t-X]\leq \mathbb{E}[(t-X)\textbf{1}\{t-X>0\}]\\
    \Rightarrow&
    (\mathbb{E}[t-X])^2\leq
    (\mathbb{E}[(t-X)\textbf{1}\{t-X>0\}])^2
\end{aligned}
$

$
\begin{aligned}
    t^2&=(\mathbb{E}[t-X])^2\\
    &\leq (\mathbb{E}[(t-X)\textbf{1}\{t-X>0\}])^2\\
    &\leq \mathbb{E}[(t-X)^2]\mathbb{E}[\textbf{1}\{t-X>0\}^2]\\
    &=\mathbb{E}[(t-X)^2]\mathbb{E}[\textbf{1}\{t-X>0\}]\\
    &\leq \mathbb{E}[(t-X)^2]\cdot \mathbb{P}(t-X>0)\\
    &=(t^2+\mathbb{E}[X^2])\cdot \mathbb{P}(X<t)
\end{aligned}
$

We can reformulate this to $\mathbb{P}(X\geq t)\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]+t^2}.$